# Run Selenium commands via google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, browser-automation

Is it possible to build a custom google chrome extension to run selenium commands when it detects a specific Url/page?

Where to begin? How would you run selenium commands via a google chrome extension?

Answer (score -1):

First install selenium [IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) and record all your test cases into it [This is to save your time in writing test cases].

Then get selenium [RC](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) binaries for your preferred language (for me its C#). Create your project and take reference of selenium RC binaries. Import all test cases from above selenium IDE in your preferred language and add those into your project.

When you will import the test cases from IDE default browser will be *chrome(i.e. Firefox). To change it to Chrome change browser type when we are creating selenium object

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*googlechrome", "http://www.google.com/");
```

To run your project you have to first start selenium server. [Here](http://seleniumforum.forumotion.net/t321-start-selenium-server) is the guideline for the same.

**Note:** You can  also use selenium web driver in place of selenium RC. And I think if you use web driver then you no need to run selenium server to execute your test cases/project.

Comment: So either way I have to run selenium? Cant i just build a extension like selenium without having to run anything on the desktop? Saucelabs they did it! so im wondering how it was done?

Comment: how do you run selenium web driver, can i build a custom chrome extension and use selenium web driver???

Comment: I ran web driver with Visual Studio. I think using web driver you can build it. Its doesn't need selenium server.

Comment: What I mean is, can I build an google chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore that uses selenium commands to perform required task? no external java app running just an extension like selenium IDE, but completely customised.

Comment: Your question is unconstructive.  Yes it can be built clearly because somebody wrote Selenium IDE, we have no idea if you can build it.  You would need to understand and be able to program in C. Then start by trying to decypher the [Chrome Web Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/search?q=Web+Driver&origq=Web+Driver&btnG=Search+Trunk).

Comment: @001 did you answer your question? please update for me